# MS Word Find Style spanning 2 lines that contains text and replace part

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, find-and-replace

I will be creating a macro for this, but first I just want to get the find/replace to function.  I have occassions in my Word document where there are 2 lines of Heading 3s in a row.  The first line contains some repeated text.  I want to search the document for all occassions of Heading 3 that includes this repeated text, and remove everything before that while simultaneously changing the style.

For example, I have this:

[image]

and want to convert it to this:

[image]

Comment: I've not used Word since Word 97, but the following worked then. If you enable wild cards, then find `First Heading*Second Heading` will match across new lines and formatting. If you replace with `Second Heading`, the formatting from `First Heading` will be retained.

Comment: I actually want to search for the repeated text portion.  So search for (star)REPEATEDTEXT(star) of style Heading 3 and only keep everything included in the second * while also converting that to Heading 2

Comment: You can (or used to be able to) include formatting in both the search and replacement strings: searching for `*REPEATEDTEXT*(<)` in style **Heading 3** and replacing with `\1` in style **Heading 2** works for me. In this case `<` is the start of the next word, and the brackets mark it as an expression which is then identified as `\1` in the replacement string.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to modify the find a bit by removing the first *.  Word freezes when I find/replace with the star in the front.

Comment: I don't see how it matches the whole of the first heading without the leading `*`, but if it works that's all you need. (It doesn't crash in '97.)

Comment: You are correct, it wasn't matching the whole line. If I add it in, it does, but I guess since my doc is 150 pages, it appears to freeze and takes several minutes to complete.  It seems like a simple enough regex, so I am not quite sure why it is so difficult for word to handle.

Comment: I can't really comment on the quality of coding in MS products. I just hope that you don't have to do this operation very often.