# Efficient Find/Replace Heading in MS Word that Contains text

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, microsoft-word-2010

I have multiple Heading 3s in MS Word.  Some of them contain specific text: "MYTEXT".  I want to find all Heading 3s that include "MYTEXT" and remove that word and all text to it's left while converting to Heading 2.

I can accomplish that by performing a regex find/replace in MS Word, but it takes about 5 minutes to run on a 150 page document making about 25 changes.  There has to be a better way!  Do you have a more efficient way to do this:

[image]

This question stemmed from another that I asked here: [MS Word Find Style spanning 2 lines that contains text and replace part](https://superuser.com/questions/1077786/ms-word-find-style-spanning-2-lines-that-contains-text-and-replace-part)

Comment: Your solutions seems to be good. 5 minutes is really too much for that document; either your system has some issues (try the same operation on another computer), either the document itself has something really increasing its complexity (large graphics / text boxes / complex structured objects...)

Comment: OK, thanks.  There isn't anything too out of the ordinary in the document, but I will look deeper at that.